# David Deutsch says "number of atoms in universe is finite", but then says "number of programs of all finite lengths is infinite". Contradiction?

Tags: cosmology, universe

From book "Fabric of reality" by David Deutsch (page 127 chapter 6 "universality and limits of computation").

> We know from quantum theory that all such variables are quantized, and therefore that, no matter how the computer works, the set of possible programs is discrete. Each program can therefore be expressed as a finite sequence of symbols in a discrete code or computer language. There are infinitely many such programs, but each one can contain only a finite number of symbols. That is because symbols are physical objects, made of matter in recognizable configurations, and one could not manufacture an infinite number of them

So, why the list of programs is infinite if the length of each program is finite?

Namely "one can contain only a finite number of symbols" contradicts "There are infinitely many such programs"

---

I look at https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/58057/109204

> The number of programs of all finite lengths is infinite. This is depressingly easy to prove. In C++, take the programs which (apart from decoration) say x=1, x=2, x=3,… (and so on for ever) and you have your infinite list of programs.

But if "one could not manufacture an infinite number of configurations of matter" then "x" cannot be infinitely big.

<sup>P.S. also, it means that energy in universe is finite, and one day we will spend all energy of universe and die, since humans are robots (update: refuted by comments below)</sup>

Comment: How does the comp-phys tag apply here? This really isn't about any comp-physics subject, but about philosophy (or at the very least why physicists are usually terrible philosophers) and definitions of finite/infinite. Since neither of those tags exist here, I am hard pressed to remove any tag. You might be interested in seeing what real philosophers would say over at [philosophy.se] than physicists here (who, again, make for terrible philosophers).

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to say that the number of possible programs is infinite. But we don't have enough atoms to write them all down.

Comment: Why do you claim that *"one can contain only a finite number of symbols" contradicts "There are infinitely many such programs"* ?

Comment: Thx for help, I realized potential vs actual infinity https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/163394/109204

Comment: @srghma I believe you're still a bit confused about this. The size (cardinality) of $\mathbb{N}$, the set of natural numbers, is infinite. However, each natural number in that set is finite.

Comment: @PM2Ring indeed, you see correctly, I told that string `xxx` is at the same time finite (by definition) and potentially infinite. Is it a contradiction?

Comment: No, each string is finite, but the collection of all strings is infinite. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actual_infinity Actual infinity is to be contrasted with potential infinity, in which a non-terminating process (such as "add 1 to the previous number") produces a sequence with no last element, and where each individual result is finite and is achieved in a finite number of steps. As a result, potential infinity is often formalized using the concept of a limit.

Comment: @PM2Ring Why you mention ”collection of all strings”? I was talking only about the "length of string xxx is finite and potentially infinite". I am not talking about "cardinality of a set of all possible programs/strings xxx"

Comment: You brought up the concept of potential infinity, but that concept does *not* apply to any of the strings Deutsch is talking about, it only applies to the collection of all strings. Each string in that collection is finite.

Answer (score 4):

There's an infinite amount of natural numbers. Even if there's only one program per given length, the total number of them will be infinite.

This is of course completely independent of the number of atoms in the universe, since computer science is a math discipline, not physics.

Comment: Am I at least right that author says that "in real universe you cannot have disk of infinite size"? Or I hallucinating. (Bing AI tells that number of atoms is infinite, but I want to know what author thinks)

Comment: `There are infinitely many such programs [of course, I agree, logically - infinitely], but each one [program] can contain only a finite number of symbols. That is because symbols are physical objects, made of matter in recognizable configurations, and one could not manufacture an infinite number of them [symbols]` . Therefore, author thinks that "hard disk is finite", right?

Comment: @srghma From the quotes you've posted so far I suppose the author is saying about manufacturing of a single program, which must be done in a finite time, and thus take only a finite amount of matter for the medium. At the same time the author seems to try to avoid making assumptions on whether the number of atoms in the whole Universe is finite. So the usual mathematical assumption that number of possible programs is the same as number of natural numbers is still not restricted.

Comment: But I cannot store ANY natural number on a hard disk, created from "finite amount of matter"

Comment: @srghma what do you mean? Your very real HDD/SSD made of finite amount of matter is storing billions of natural numbers (AKA bytes) right now.

Comment: I mean I cannot store on my disk the number greater than `2^size_of_my_disk_in_bits - 1` (if disk is 2, then xx, then max number is 11 = 3). Since author says ”programs should be stored on finite amount of matter" I want author to change sentence "There are infinitely many such programs, but each one can contain only a finite number of symbols." To "There are infinitely many programs, if each one can contain infinite number of symbols. There are finitely many programs, if each one can contain finite number of symbols."

Comment: @srghma For each program made of finite number of symbols there exists a finite medium that can contain it. Just as in real life, if your, say, video doesn't fit on a CD, you use a DVD... or an SSD... or an HDD, or something larger.

Comment: Cannot go "larger" indefinitely many times, if (as you told yourself) "finite amount of matter [is available in] the medium"

Comment: @srghma if your program has a finite size, you need to only allocate your storage once: to fit this particular program. And do so for any program you want to create. Again, the idea of doing so infinitely many times is just as (un)physical as the idea of actually having an infinite number of physically stored programs (even if each of them is only 1 symbol long). You can't possibly do this in a finite time, regardless of how much material resource you have. But mathematically yes, there do exist an infinite amount of such sequences of symbols.

Comment: Thx for help, I realized potential vs actual infinity https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/163394/109204

Answer (score 3):

> Namely "one can contain only a finite number of symbols" contradicts "There are infinitely many such programs."

No contradiction. You are confused by the observation that each natural number is finite, yet the cardinality of the set of the natural numbers is not finite (since there is no largest number).

Comment: I agree that logically (given infinite disk space)  "There are infinitely many such programs.", but he tells "could not manufacture an infinite number of them [symbols]", and I see a finite disk before my eyes, I see a program, stored as finite string xxxxxxxxxxxxxx where x is either 0 or 1. So, why he tells "There are infinitely many such programs, but each one can contain only a finite number of symbols." ??? He should tell "There are FINITELY many such programs (each one can contain only a finite number of symbols), since you could not manufacture an infinite number of symbols." !!

Comment: @srghma But the question about *manufacturing* is a different question than how many *could* be manufactured (given infinite resources). The trivial answer is, since all resources we may use are finite, yes, there are only finitely many such programs. Is that where the cognitive barrier lies?

Comment: Yes... I realized it's potential vs actual infinity https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/163394/109204

Answer (score 1):

Any given program is of some finite length $N$. There is no upper bound to $N$ so the number of possible programs is not finite.

The claim that there is some upper bound to the size of a program that could be constructed depends on various details of cosmology and physics. There are cosmological models that allow an indefinitely large number of computational steps and indefinitely large memory, such as

https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0302076

There is a lot we don't know about cosmology such as the nature of dark energy and there are a lot of unsolved problems

https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.06142

So anyone who claims to know that only a finite amount of computation or memory is allowed by physics is wrong.

Comment: Good to know that there is a chance we will not die

Comment: what you think about the prediction for universe by Sean Carroll in YouTube videos "biggest ideas in the universe" namely "there will be 3 phases of the universe: matter phase (we live here), only black holes, and (since Hawking told that black holes evaporate) only plain energy. Since energy is wavy - all combinations of energies are re-tried, and there will be a combination of energies equal to the start of the universe, and that's how new universe blow up" (and then disappear, and maybe we will not be able to escape the death of universe)"?

Comment: I wrote about this here https://srghma.github.io/universe#who-we-are-in-this-universe

Comment: I'm not familiar with what Sean Carroll said and I won't comment on a second hand account of it.